# HTML Video Not Working When Hosted on a Different Server

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I have created a website and there is a video I have used on it.

When I have uploaded the site to my own hosting everything works fine, however, when on my clients host, the video doesn't play in chrome, and says invalid source on IE.

**My code is as follows:**

```
<div id="Main_Video_Video">
         <video width="520" height="292" controls poster="videos/Illumina-Poster.jpg">
         <source src="videos/Illumina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
         <source src="videos/Illumina.ogg" type="video/ogg">
         <source src="videos/Illumina.webm" type="video/webm">
         <object data="videos/Illumina.mp4" width="520" height="292">
         <embed src="videos/Illumina.swf" width="520" height="292">
         </object> 
         </video>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share link to site, or check if videos are in correct relative folder.

Comment: Working version is here: [link](http://swillis.co.uk/tests/ronaldmasters/index.html)

None working version here: [link](http://www.ronaldmasters.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

404 - Not found. 
It has nothing to do with the video itself.
Have you copied all the 5 files into the videos directory ?

On a windows server, check if the mime-types are allowed and that the server has read-access in that directory.

If your client's (server) machine is a Linux/Unix system, the file names are case-sensitive (capital & non-capital letters are not the same).

Comment: Problem solved, the client had bought hosting from their old designer, ad the studio had settings that meant they needed to allow the videos on their side (which they charge for doing).

So after spending half a day pulling my hair out, at least it is sorted